# new div after my script hide button

Tags: jquery

I have number of buttons like this one:

```
<button class="btn btn-default moreCommentsBtn" feel="subComments" allowreply="0" refid="348" pagename="yard" maxresult="20" startrow="20">MORE COMMENTS</button>
```

"refid" is unique.

When there is no more comment I hide the specific button:

```
$( 'button[ refID=' + <?PHP echo $refID ?> + ']' ).addClass( 'hideBox' );
```

I would also like to print div, instead the button, that says "there are no more comments".

how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like..

```
$( 'button[ refID=' + <?PHP echo $refID ?> + ']' ).addClass( 'hideBox' ).parent().append("<p>There are no more comments</p>");
```

You can also use `<div>`, instead of `<p>`.

And to make it more elegant, you can have a class something like `.nocomments` which you can hide immediately if you ever want to hide this notice.

And if you want more specific control you can also use the `refid` to make the unique `id` like: `id="'com' + refid"` of that `div/p` element. then you can hide/remove that very specific div with the `refid`.